# Transferring Custom DOM Node Attributes to Dijit Widgets

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm working on some code that uses custom attributes on DOM nodes. These are necessary for particular logic that is used. The custom attributes are set on input elements such as dropdowns and text input fields and are of the format...

```
<input type="text" myCustomId="blah"...
```

This all works fine with standard HTML inputs. However, we are looking to use some Dijit widgets in place of the standard inputs to achieve a specific look & feel.
The DOM is parsed onLoad and the widgets are loaded (we set data-dojo-type to specify the widget).
The problem is Dojo/Dijit doesn't preserve the custom attributes. They get lost in the parsing.

Is it possible to specify custom attributes that a Dijit widget should use?

Edit:

Heres some sample HTML that highlights the problem. The "custom" attribute is being lost...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/_static/js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
<script src="http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/_static/js/dojo/dojo.js">    </script>
<script>require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/TextBox"]);</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
<label for="firstname">Test: </label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" custom="test" value="testing testing"
data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" id="firstname" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution based on this article...

http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/html5data-attributes

Essentially if I add "data-" in front of our custom attributes, the dojo parser preserves the custom attribute in the widget. It doesn't place the attribute on the top most node of the widget but it does enough for us to look it up

Comment: The relevant code is in `_WidgetBase` with the `set` method. Only things that start with `data-*`, `aria-*`, or `role*` will get copied over when Dojo starts messing with the widget's main DOM node. You might be able to make a workaround by subclassing `dijit/form/TextBox` and setting the `attributeMap`, although it'll probably be broken in 2.0.

Comment: Thats for the clarification Darien. I specifically didn't want to subclass any widgets as going forward that approach can be a bit of a maintenance nightmare

Answer (score 0):

Try use `data-dojo-props='urCustomID=XXX'`, then you could obtain it by `get("urCustomID")`.

Comment: No joy. Tried...

   data-dojo-props="myCustomAttribute:'abc123'".

But it still gets lost. There is no sign of the custom attribute anywhere in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

the custom attributes added are retained by the widgets indeed. But, they are case-insensitive. According to the example you provided in your question, try accessing it by,

```
registry.byId('field_id').get('mycustomid')
```

or

```
dijit.byId('field_id').get('mycustomid')
```

Let me give a simple example:-

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
    function func() {
        alert(dijit.byId('namefld').get('customid'));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <input type="text" customId='mango' dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="namefld" name="namefld"/>
    <button onclick='func()'>click</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, I'll give that a go today but I've been inspecting the HTML of the widgets in Firebug and the custom attributes are not on the widget at all. And there is no sign of them if I just do a search for them.

Comment: Please refer the screen shot image, that confirms, the custom attributes can be viewed/accessed in firebug. - 
http://i.imgur.com/ImCjr1n.jpg

Comment: hhhmmm, I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. Your example isn't quite what I was describing. While you set dojoType, the input is not being parsed onLoad and replaced with a widget as you still have the standard HTML input there.

See...

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/TextBox.html

If you run the first sample and inspect the HTML you will see the widget is made up of some nested div's with the input inside.
What is happening for me is the creation of this widget is losing the custom attributes.

Comment: i was just using the legacy syntax (version<=1.7). But, it is same what that example you have quoted. 'dojoType" & 'data-dojo-type' are same. Also, i have used the old syntax of 'require', which has been replaced by the AMD design. It's only the syntax that is different, but it works the same. I have tried your example code without any changes, and it works too. - pls refer the screen shot http://i.imgur.com/aIt8461.jpg

Comment: Hi vivek,

Your sample was the same but what I was highlighting was that the HTML doesn't seem to have been replaced with the widget html which gets called by "<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>".

Comment: Vivek, I believe he means HTML element attributes, but all your screenshots are pointing at the Widget (javascript object) and its instance properties.